# JavaScript: Using Object.defineProperties()

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to learn how to use Object.defineProperties().  I'm using the following code:

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};

Object.defineProperties(Person, {
    sayHi : {
        get : function() {return "Hello";},
        enumerable : true
    },
    sayBye : {
        get : function() {return "Bye";},
        enumerable : true
    }
});


var john = new Person('John', 'Doe');
console.log(john.sayHi());
```

But I keep getting:

```
TypeError: john.sayHi is not a function
console.log(john.sayHi());
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to define properties on `Person.prototype`, not the on `Person` constructor. This isn't at all a problem with how you're using `Object.defineProperties`, but may be a problem with your understanding of how prototypal inheritance works in JavaScript. (Note you're missing a comma before `sayBye`, but I assume that's a typo in the question only.)

Comment: It should still work. I'm following a tutorial, and exact same code is working when the tutor runs it.

Comment: Can you share a link to the tutorial? In addition to your incorrect prototype setup, also note that `sayHi` and `sayBye` have getters that return *strings*, not functions. Even if you correctly do `Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype, ...)`, then `john.sayHi` will not be a function; it will be the string "`Hello`".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing comma; yes, it was a typo in the question, but the code I'm running does have the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are not defining sayHi as a function. This is how to define it as a function:

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
// Define the properties on the prototype, not the Person object itself
Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype, {
    sayHi : {
        get : function() {
          return function() {
            return "Hello, I am " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
          };
        },
        enumerable : true
    },
    sayBye : {
        get : function() {
          return function() {
            return "Bye";
          };
        },
        enumerable : true
    }
});

var john = new Person('John', 'Doe');
console.log(john.sayHi());
console.log(john.sayBye());
```

To be precise: in your code, john.sayHi returns the "Hello" string, which is a string primitive, and therefore definitely not a function ;-)

The get function for the property must return a function in order to achieve what you want.

To give you a longer answer, see this following other implementation, taking fully advantage of two things: first the new features from ES5 (`Object.create()`) and ES6  (`Object.defineProperties()`) and the prototypal nature of JS (no use of `new` operator, prototypal inheritance):

```
var Person = {
    init: function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
};

Object.defineProperties(Person, {
    sayHi : {
        get : function() {return function() {return "Hello, I am " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;}},
        enumerable : true
    },
    sayBye : {
        get : function() {return function() {return "Bye";};},
        enumerable : true
    }
});

var Employee = Object.create(Person); // Employee inherits from Person

Employee.init = function(firstName, lastName, position) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.position = position;
};

Object.defineProperties(Employee, {
    introduce : {
        get : function() {return function() {
            return this.sayHi() + ", " + this.position;
        }},
        enumerable : true
    },
    farewell : {
        get: function() {return function() {
            return this.sayBye() + ", it was a pleasure to meet you";
        }},
        enumerable: true
    }
});

var john = Object.create(Employee); // john inherits from Employee
john.init('John', 'Doe', 'Manager');

console.log(john.sayHi()); // Inherited from Person
console.log(john.introduce()); // Inherited from Employee
console.log(john.sayBye()); // Inherited from Person
console.log(john.farewell()); // Inherited from Employee
```

[JSFIddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/spvn04q9/)

Comment: Probably worth making mention of the somewhat important fact that you are applying it to `Person.prototype` and not just `Person`, so you can call it as `john.sayHi()`, rather than `Person.sayHi()`

Comment: @laruiss:  That works like a charm since you are defining it on the prototype. Any idea why it won't work if I define the property on Person?  As I mentioned, in the tutorial that I'm following, the author defines the property on Person, and it seems to work for him.

Comment: Well, my answer might surprise you, but... I would guess that he does not use the `new` operator, does he?

Comment: It's a screencast that I'm watching, and actually he does use the new operation on Person to create the john object.

Comment: OK, could you give us the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
get : function() {return "Hello";}   with

get : function() {return function() {return "Hello";};}
```